# How many CPU cores does Blender support and make sense?

Tags: gpu

everybody,

i want to "build" a new computer for myself. Blender benefits from several cores. How many does Blender support and how many do actually make sense?

Greetings 
Ralf

Comment: Short answer: Everything you can get. So the question is what do you'd like to pay...

Comment: Thanks for the fast Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more, the better in most cases, but you do need to be aware of single thread performance as well. If you get a processor with lots of cores that has very poor single thread performance and use it for work, you might struggle with some operations that cannot use all of the cores. Generally physics simulations tend to use multiple cores a bit less efficiently because they tend to need the results of previous calculations in order to continue so the calculations are difficult to do in parallel. Some other every day modelling tasks also suffer from this. For rendering - the more cores you have, the better, unless you render loads of really fast frames(seconds) in which case preparing the scene for rendering might take more time than actually rendering and during the preparation there are some things done with single thread only - in that case it might be slow.

Answer (score 0):

It is same like sugar.. more you will add more sweeten you will get.

if you are using windows 64bit, then your windows can support upto 256, so blender can't lead this, but it doesn't matter at all, but more threads do matter. When you render anything in cycles, those boxes are actually thread.  So If you have a multi processor system(where windows can use only two)... so as many core you will have it will use.

Better you don't invest in expensive CPUs unless you are really professional in this, otherwise fewer cores with good performance is greater choice than learning on 256cores! .

Comment: After a certain amount, adding sugar will not increase perceived sweetness. I would remove the analogy.

Comment: okay.. just add sugar upto. 256cores! :D

Comment: Fair enough, that makes sense. ^^

Comment: I don't think it make sense to talk about numbers like that. Are there even mother boards that support enough processors and any graphics cards that still make sense to work with 3d at the same time? It would not make sense financially and logically either, because not all of every day operations in Blender support more than one thread. It would not be a good advice in any context I can think of.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys I think you missed my last line in answer. It's really not worthy to pay only for such processors which have so many cores. https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/processors/xeon/e7-processors/e7-8890-v4.html is a processor with 24cores. max 8 processors can be used together... you will get 192cores.. but as I said earlier, it doesn't matter at all but yes threads do for Blender.

Comment: I was talking about adding sugar. I don't think it gets any sweeter after around 8 cores if the machine is used for work as well(in addition to rendering) even for professionals. It would be logical to have a processor with good single thread performance and then a separate solution for rendering if we go up from there. Anyone who really needs anything different/more would not be asking questions.